# Trouble creating a new git repository on the GitHub Desktop app

Tags: github, github-for-windows

I'm trying to create a new repository, but any location I select in my D:\ drive results in the message "This directory appears to be a Git repository.  Would you like to add this repository instead?"  The "Create repository" button [is unresponsive.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PblFE.png)  Not sure how to correct this.

Comment: Have you tried clicking “add this repository” instead? You’ve probably created one under that path already.

Comment: Yes I have.  When I do, it only displays "D:\".  Shortly after, I get the message "Can't find 'D:\'"  I can create new repositories in my C:\ drive, but if I try to create any in the D:\ drive, I get the "this appears to be a repository" message.  Is there a way to remove any/all directories in the D:\ drive?

Comment: haha I’m glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION:

I figured it out.  I've been experimenting with git and I had used the command "git init" from the command window.

To correct this, I just deleted the repository that I had created in the D:\ location.